# UISearchController's searchbar is not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, searchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am not able to get responding events on tapping UISearchController's search bar in iOS 8.

I am displaying custom view with dim background like alert view appearance,  on pressing button in a view, where custom view has UISearchController's search bar as sub view. Programmatically added searchController. When I try to touch search bar, it is not responding in iOS 8 whereas I have added search bar with UISearchDisplayController for iOS 7, it is working fine.

I have viewController A with navigation bar. In viewController A, I have a button. On pressing button, I am trying to show view as custom view with dim background like alert view appearance. So I have added following line in button method.

```
class_name *view = [[class_name alloc] initWithNibName:@"xib_name" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:view];
```

Xib file of class_name has dim background with subviews like searchController's search bar.

Instead of

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:view];
```

added

```
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

UISearchController's search bar is working now but i am not able to get transparent background view, instead black background appears.

I need to display previous views content and on top that current views content like alert view.

Please guide me in objective-C.

Comment: did you set the delegate to self?

Comment: @sasquatch  Ya. UISearchController's search bar is working fine in normal view, when I try to do in custom view, it is not responding.

Comment: Perhaps something in the view hierarchy is interfering with touch gestures.  Please show code, so we can see how your view and searchBar are setup.

Comment: @PetahChristian UISearchController's Searchbar touch is working now, but I am not able to get transparent background. I need to display previous views content and on top that current views content like alert view.